# Ошибка приложения Angular 5 на браузере IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

Столкнулся с проблемой. При запуске приложения на IE 11, вылетает ошибка:

> SCRIPT1046: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode
>   main.bundle.js

Ошибка выскакивает на месте где стоит `"use strict";` после чего идет `eval(.....`

---

```
eval("/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"a\", function() { return UserProfileComponent; });\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__ = __webpack_require__(\"../../../core/esm5/core.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__ = __webpack_require__(\"../../../forms/esm5/forms.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__angular_material__ = __webpack_require__(\"../../../material/esm5/material.es5.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__service_user_service__ = __webpack_require__(\"../../../../../src/app/service/user.service.ts\");\nvar __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {\r\n    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;\r\n    if (typeof Reflect === \"object\" && typeof Reflect.decorate === \"function\") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);\r\n    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;\r\n    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;\r\n};\r\nvar __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {\r\n    if (typeof Reflect === \"object\" && typeof Reflect.metadata === \"function\") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);\r\n};\r\nvar __param = (this && this.__param) || function (paramIndex, decorator) {\r\n    return function (target, key) { decorator(target, key, paramIndex); }\r\n};\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nvar UserProfileComponent = (function () {\r\n    function UserProfileComponent(data, fb, userService) {\r\n        this.data = data;\r\n        this.fb = fb;\r\n        this.userService = userService;\r\n        this.submitted = false;\r\n        this.editMode = false;\r\n        this.submitDisabled = true;\r\n    }\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {\r\n        var _this = this;\r\n        this.user = this.data;\r\n        this.buildForm();\r\n        this.userProfileChanges = this.userProfile.valueChanges.subscribe(function (form) {\r\n            _this.submitDisabled = !_this.userProfileForm.form.valid;\r\n        });\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.buildForm = function () {\r\n        this.userProfile = this.fb.group({\r\n            login: this.fb.group({\r\n                id: [this.user.id],\r\n                alias: [this.user.alias, [\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required,\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].minLength(3),\r\n                        this.nosSpaceValidator\r\n                    ]],\r\n                passwords: this.fb.group({\r\n                    password: ['test123AAA', [\r\n                            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required,\r\n                            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].minLength(10),\r\n                            this.passwordValidator()\r\n                        ]],\r\n                    passwordrepeat: ['test123AAA', [\r\n                            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required\r\n                        ]],\r\n                }, { validator: this.matchPassword }),\r\n                emailsList: [false],\r\n                email: [this.user.email, [\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required,\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].email\r\n                    ]]\r\n            }),\r\n            personal: this.fb.group({\r\n                title: [this.user.title],\r\n                name: [this.user.name, [\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required,\r\n                        this.nosSpaceValidator\r\n                    ]],\r\n                forename: [this.user.forename, [\r\n                        __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"l\" /* Validators */].required,\r\n                        this.nosSpaceValidator\r\n                    ]],\r\n                company: [this.user.company],\r\n                department: [this.user.department],\r\n                street: [this.user.street],\r\n                zipCode: [this.user.zipCode],\r\n                city: [this.user.city],\r\n                deleted: [this.user.deleted]\r\n            }),\r\n            accounting: this.fb.group({\r\n                personalnumber: [this.user.personalnumber],\r\n                costPerHour: [this.user.costPerHour]\r\n            })\r\n        });\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.nosSpaceValidator = function (control) {\r\n        return control.value && control.value.replace(/ /g, '').length === 0 ? { 'noSpace': true } : null;\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.matchPassword = function (groupControl) {\r\n        var password = groupControl.get('password').value;\r\n        var passwordrepeat = groupControl.get('passwordrepeat').value;\r\n        return password !== passwordrepeat ? { 'notMatches': { passwordrepeat: passwordrepeat } } : null;\r\n    };\r\n    /**\r\n     * cancel changes\r\n     */\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.resetUserProfileForm = function () {\r\n        // this.user = this.userService.getUser(1);\r\n        this.userProfile.reset({\r\n            login: {\r\n                alias: this.user.alias,\r\n                passwords: {\r\n                    password: this.user.password,\r\n                    passwordrepeat: this.user.password,\r\n                },\r\n                email: this.user.email\r\n            },\r\n            personal: {\r\n                title: this.user.title,\r\n                name: this.user.name,\r\n                forename: this.user.forename,\r\n                company: this.user.company,\r\n                department: this.user.department,\r\n                street: this.user.street,\r\n                zipCode: this.user.zipCode,\r\n                city: this.user.city,\r\n                deleted: this.user.deleted\r\n            },\r\n            accounting: {\r\n                personalnumber: this.user.personalnumber,\r\n                costPerHour: this.user.costPerHour\r\n            }\r\n        });\r\n        this.changeEditMode();\r\n        this.submitDisabled = true;\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.changeEditMode = function () {\r\n        this.editMode = !this.editMode;\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.passwordValidator = function () {\r\n        var _this = this;\r\n        return function (control) {\r\n            var password = typeof control.value === 'string' ? control.value : control.value[0];\r\n            var containName = false;\r\n            var criteria = 0;\r\n            if (password.toUpperCase() != password) {\r\n                // has lower case letters\r\n                criteria++;\r\n            }\r\n            if (password.toLowerCase() != password) {\r\n                // has upper case letters\r\n                criteria++;\r\n            }\r\n            if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(password) === false) {\r\n                // has special characters\r\n                criteria++;\r\n            }\r\n            if (/\\d/.test(password) === true) {\r\n                // has numbers\r\n                criteria++;\r\n            }\r\n            if (_this.userProfileForm.value && (password.includes(_this.userProfileForm.value.login.alias) ||\r\n                password.includes(_this.userProfileForm.value.personal.name) ||\r\n                password.includes(_this.userProfileForm.value.personal.forename))) {\r\n                // can’t contain the user name or parts of the user’s full name\r\n                containName = true;\r\n            }\r\n            return (criteria >= 3 && password.length >= 10 && !containName) ? null : { 'passwordRules': { password: password } };\r\n        };\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.onSubmit = function (_a) {\r\n        var value = _a.value, valid = _a.valid;\r\n        this.submitted = true;\r\n        for (var formKey in value) {\r\n            if (value[formKey]) {\r\n                for (var key in value[formKey]) {\r\n                    if (key === 'passwords') {\r\n                        // this.user['password'] = sha256(value[formKey][key]['password']);\r\n                    }\r\n                    else {\r\n                        this.user[key] = value[formKey][key];\r\n                    }\r\n                }\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n        // this.userService.updateUserData(this.user).then(function () {\r\n        this.editMode = !this.editMode;\r\n        // }.bind(this));\r\n    };\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.updateUserProfilePhoto = function ($event) {\r\n        var files = $event.target.files || $event.srcElement.files;\r\n        var file = files[0];\r\n        var formData = new FormData();\r\n        formData.append('file', file);\r\n        // this.userService.updateUserPhoto(formData);\r\n    };\r\n    // unsubscribe from  listeners\r\n    UserProfileComponent.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {\r\n        if (this.userProfileChanges) {\r\n            this.userProfileChanges.unsubscribe();\r\n        }\r\n    };\r\n    __decorate([\r\n        Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__[\"ViewChild\"])('userProfileForm'),\r\n        __metadata(\"design:type\", Object)\r\n    ], UserProfileComponent.prototype, \"userProfileForm\", void 0);\r\n    UserProfileComponent = __decorate([\r\n        Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__[\"Component\"])({\r\n            selector: 'app-user-profile',\r\n            template: 'passed in {{ data }}',\r\n            template: __webpack_require__(\"../../../../../src/app/component/header/user-profile/user-profile.component.html\"),\r\n            styles: [__webpack_require__(\"../../../../../src/app/component/header/user-profile/user-profile.component.scss\")],\r\n            encapsulation: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__[\"ViewEncapsulation\"].None,\r\n        }),\r\n        __param(0, Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__[\"Inject\"])(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__angular_material__[\"a\" /* MAT_DIALOG_DATA */])),\r\n        __metadata(\"design:paramtypes\", [Object, __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_forms__[\"b\" /* FormBuilder */],\r\n            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__service_user_service__[\"a\" /* UserService */]])\r\n    ], UserProfileComponent);\r\n    return UserProfileComponent;\r\n}());\r\n\r\n//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,
```

Comment: Вообще-то сам тайпскрипт должен тебе показать, где ошибка.

Comment: увы, но не показывает. Проект на других браузерах запускается без проблем. На одном ie эта ошибка

Comment: С ошибкой ясно - повторяющиеся свойства в литеральной записи объекта. Тайпскрипт должен был сказать. Если не говорит, то смотри в отладчике, где конкретно ошибка, и исправляй её.